# Refresh Issue on the form when the dialog closes

Tags: axapta, x++

I have a form(for which the datasource is Table A ) from which i am calling a dialog and i enter few parameters and click on Ok. The process fills up data in Table A .

Once i close the dialog, it does fill up the table and does not show in form , i will have to do a refresh the form(pressing F5 ) . how is this possible via Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've blogged about this, so here's also some insight on how to refresh a form's DataSource:

http://devexpp.blogspot.com.br/2012/02/refresh-datasource-and-retain-position.html

Basically, all you have to do is call the *research()* method, but there's also some tricks to retain the position of the refreshed DataSource.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this very popular [tutorial by Vanya Kashperuk](http://kashperuk.blogspot.com.es/2010/03/tutorial-reread-refresh-research.html) will help.  It is about how to refresh data presented in a form, below are your options:

```
formDataSource.refresh();
formDataSource.research([true]);
formDataSource.reread();
formDataSource.executeQuery();
```