# Dynamically reload a table in a form programatically

Tags: forms, axapta

I have a form in Dynamics AX which displays a table of two columns in a grid. I also have a button on the form. I am overriding the **clicked** method of the button to update the **Address** field of the table. For example, here's my **X++** code:

```
void clicked()
{
    AddressTable addr;    
    ttsBegin;
    select forUpdate addr where addr.addressID == 1;
    addr.Address = "new address";
    addr.update();
    ttsCommit;
    super();     
    // reload table here
}
```

What I would like to do is to add a code to the **clicked** function which will reload (re-select) the updated records and show them in the form without a need of reopening the window or refreshing it using **F5** (for example).

I went through forums and AX documentation and found a few methods like **refresh** and **reread**, but they are **FormDataSource** class methods and I failed to make it happen inside the **clicked** handler above.

So, what I really want to accomplish programaticallyis what **F5** does behind the scenes when clicked on an open form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe just `addressTable_ds.research(true);` will do the job.

See also [Refresh Issue on the form when the dialog closes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114112/refresh-issue-on-the-form-when-the-dialog-closes/10122321#10122321).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. One questions please. I keep getting this error; when I try to access my table datasource through `addr.dataSource().research(true);` it's saying that "object was not initialized". Can you please tell me how to correctly use my table datasource and its methods correctly. I couldn't find a complete example on the web...

Comment: There are hundreds of examples on `research` in existing forms,  just search! `addr.datasource()` implies that your `addr` buffer is from a datasource, but looking at your code, it is definitely not. Use `addressTable_ds` or whatever your datasource is named postfixed with `_ds`.

Comment: There is a usage example of _research(true);_ in the AOT\Forms\ProjTable entity, or at least in AX 2009 there is.